# how to add a few results from index match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How to I add a few index match results pleasE? is there a quicker way to add all instead of add each index match one by one?

[image]

Comment: What about using this: `=Sum(B4:D4)`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a fairly general way of doing it (not much shorter in this particular case - but you can fill in up to three departments and up to four shops)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$4,{"Depart Central","",""},0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$1:$E$1,{"Shop1","Shop2","Shop3",""},0))*$B$2:$E$4)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom. thanks for the formula, does it have to be "Depart Central","Shop1"?  anyway I can use A4  or B1?

Comment: You can get the same result from =SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$4,A4,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$1:$E$1,B1:D1,0))*$B$2:$E$4) but {B1,C1,D1} doesn't work so it's not as flexible  - you couldn't do Shop1 and Shop3 only that way because it's not a continuous range. BTW you can leave out the empty strings "".

Answer (score 0):

See attached pic below.  You can use `SUMPRODUCT` and add the criteria together like this:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$4=A4)*(($B$1:$E$1=B1)+($B$1:$E$1=C1)+($B$1:$E$1=D1))*($B$4:$E$4))
```

Please note `A4, B1, C1 and D1` in the formula can be changed to the criteria  you want to use.

This should work for you but try and let me know.

**REVISED:**

This is what I meant to have a table for criteria.

So with this formula entered in `cell C8`, you should get your result.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$4=A8)*(($B$1:$E$1=B8)+($B$1:$E$1=B9)+($B$1:$E$1=B10))*(OFFSET(A1,MATCH(A8,$A$1:$A$4,0)-1,1,,COUNTA(B1:L1))))
```

I just replaced `$B$4:$E$4` with `OFFSET(A1,MATCH(A8,$A$1:$A$4,0)-1,1,,COUNTA(B1:L1))` so it can find the range based on the first criteria.  But I don't know how to check criteria 2 dynamically at this point.  Thought about using `OFFSET` but it only works for consecutive range.  Sorry.

[image]

Comment: but does I have to manually change $B$4:$E$4 if the department changes..

Comment: I will say make another table that you can enter your criteria so you can lookup and that way you don't need to change in the formula which is not very user intuitive.  Or use Tom Sharpe's method if your data will layout like this way.

Comment: thanks for the reply Ian, sorry how to lookup to auto change the range of (b4:E4) to b3:E3 if it is depart south please?

Comment: See the *REVISED* part of my answer.  Using `OFFSET` should take care of that requirement.